# Get the name of the build container from service when using gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, networking, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using network per build in gitlab runner.  My build container can resolve the alias of the service, but I can't figure out how to get the ip address of the build container from the service container.

```
test_grservice:
  stage: test
  image: opencpi18:5000/testservice
  script:
    - python3 test.py
  services:
    - name: opencpi18:5000/grservice
      alias: grservice
  tags:
    - hw
```

Specifically I can do the following from the build container:

```
ping grservice
```

What would I type in the service container to ping the build container?

This link claims that I should be able to resolve the build job container name from the service, but I don't know what the build job container name is:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the link you provided:

> The build container is resolvable via the build alias as well as it’s GitLab assigned hostname.

Did you try that (i.e. `ping build`)?

Comment: It is also worth noting that the service cannot resolve "build" when it starts because the "build" container doesn't exist.  Once the "build" container exists, then it will resolve.

Comment: I use gitlab 13.6.7 , and it seems that the `build`   cannot resolved by service.